# No access privileges opening document from Office Online (365) on Mac

Tags: macos, sharepoint, office365

We're developing a Microsoft Office Add-in and encounter issues switching from editing a document on Office Online to `Edit in Word`. Even without the add-in, the issue can be reproduced.

The user which is a registered **Microsoft Outlook account** has access to a **shared directory** (folder) on a **Sharepoint site**. *Edit: Opening a file on the users own OneDrive works.*

[image]

results in a prompt from the Office for Mac to ask the user to sign-in.

[image]

After the sign-in, Office for Mac shows a dialog saying `user does not have access privileges` message in Word on Mac.

[image]

The user which is a registered **Microsoft Outlook account** has access to a **shared directory** (folder) on a **Sharepoint site**. The user is registered as an **external user** (through invitation which has been accepted) on an Azure Active Directory and is part of a user group on this Active Directory which can edit the folder. The user has access to the directory via the group permission, not directly.

Browsing the folder via `https://[app].sharepoint.com/sites/pub/Shared%20Documents/[SharedDirectory]` as the user works. Documents can be opened and edited on **Microsoft Online**. Switching from Online edition to `Edit in Word` or `Edit in Excel` fails after signing-in with the user.

The very same user is already signed-in to Microsoft Office for Mac and should actually not be prompted again to authenticate.

[image]

From the moment of signing-in, Word and Excel behave different.
Word shows a dialog saying `Word cannot open the document: user does not have access privileges.`

Excel keeps prompting the user to sign-in.
[image]

On Windows 10, Edit in Word/Excel works. If the user is not signed-in to Microsoft Office for Windows yet, a prompt appears similar to the Office for Mac, asking the user to sign in. After the sign-in, the user is signed-in Office for Windows, the document opens and can be edited and saved.

Is there a way to ensure that shared documents can be edited through Office for Mac?

The Mac version used is `15.37 (170815)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The described behavior could be verified by the Microsoft Support team. I created a post in UserVoice and encourage everyone with the same issue to upvote for it and get notified about changes through that:

https://office365.uservoice.com/forums/264636-general/suggestions/31387858-enable-viewing-and-editing-of-shared-documents-on